# Types and forms of adjectives in German

Tags: adjective

I am reading [this article](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/adjectives#:%7E:text=There%20are%20three%20types%20of,%3A%20predicative%2C%20adverbial%20and%20attributive.). In the beginning it is said that there are three type of adjective:

1. Predicative
2. Adverbial
3. Attributive

Then later there is a mention of the comparitive forms of adjective:

1. Basic
2. Comparitive
3. Superlative

In the article, only for superlative was a tie in to the three type of adjective said; how to form superlative in the three type of adjective. However, does there exist the three form of adjective for the Predicative and adverbial form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Predicative* means that the adjective is an argument of a verb that takes a predicative phrase rather than objects. Such verbs are for example *sein, werden, bleiben, gelten als* and some more. It's not declined then.

- Das **ist** **leicht / leichter / am leichtesten.**

*Adverbial* means that the adjective describes a verb or another adjective. It's also not declined then.

- Sie **macht** es ihm **leicht / leichter / am leichtesten.**
- Sie macht es ihm **leicht / leichter / am leichtesten verständlich.**

*Attributive* means that the adjective describes a noun. It's declined then.

- Das ist **die leichte / leichtere / leichteste Aufgabe.**

Comment: Valid points but this is not what I asked.

Comment: So what is your question then? I listed the basic, comparative, and superlative forms for all three uses.

Comment: There are forms of adjective based on comparisons (Basic, comapritive, Superlative). In the article, for superlative the the three type of adjective are explained. I am asking if the the three type exit for basic and comparitive as well

Comment: Yes. As I had put it. Do you see how each of the three uses has those three different forms in my answer?

Comment: Ah oops I had misunderstood the forms. After rereading it again and checking your answer again , I found it answers.